# Is It Possible to Add SQL Reporting Service to SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I joined a windows host who runs SQL Server 2008 Express (Negative Surprise)! I think this is wrong since a host should expect some medium companies join them so they should put at least standard version. I don't know much about dba, but this is my suggestion. Am i right?

OK! Here is my question, the host has SQL Reporting Service as an extra feature added to the SQL Server 2008 Express. Does this Reporting Service suffice a small business reporting needs? Is the reporting service on Express is too limited comparing to the enterprise one?

The support team told SQL Reporting Service on Express has same settings as the one on Enterprise.

Any idea? Please advise ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have the same features as Enterprise. See the Reporting Services node in the [edition comparison matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx) here for some idea of the differences.

Unfortunately I don't have first hand experience of using RS on Express Editions so can't comment on exactly how limited it is.